# How do I remove a schema_plugin from a geonetwork instance?

Tags: geonetwork, plugins, iso-19115, iso-19139

Currently running a geonetwork 4.2.0 instance in a sandbox environment and I need to remove all but one schema_plugin, iso19115-3.2018. However I am unable to remove the iso19139 plugin without causing errors. Just wondering if anyone has done this before

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to remove them?